# Translation not working for captcha module

Tags: magento-1, localisation, bug, captcha

I have activated magento admin login form captcha. I keep getting the message "*Incorrect CAPTCHA*" When i enter an incorrect captcha code, I want to show the german language text instead of english, since it is a german shop.

I copied the file

> app\locale\en_US\Mage_Captcha.csv

to

> app\locale\de_DE\Mage_Captcha.csv

and changed the line

```
"Incorrect CAPTCHA.","Incorrect CAPTCHA."
```

to

```
"Incorrect CAPTCHA.","Falsches CAPTCHA."
```

But it still shows **Incorrect CAPTCHA.**, even after clearing the cache (cache is also disabled.)

Comment: Hello, have you redeployed after making the change?

Comment: are you using magento's default captcha? Or you are using any third party module? Did you check if other translations are working perfectly or not?

Comment: I am using magentos captcha. I did not checked yet if other translations work.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/609

Comment: Think Oleksandrs answer is completly right .... to fix it w/o touching core files just add a mini-extension with a config.xml that contains these line.

Comment: I agree with @sv3n. Best solution from Magento - don't touch core files. My solution was for old Magento store, that will be moved to Magento 2 soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My shop is Magento 1.9.3.1 and I found the same problem, that Magento_Captcha module don't have translation. I tried different solution and I finally found that in this file:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
```

Missing information about which file to use for translation. I added this and translation start working:

```
<frontend>
    ...
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <captcha>
                <files>
                    <default>Mage_Captcha.csv</default>
                </files>
            </captcha>
        </modules>
    </translate>
    ...
</frontend>
```

**Note:** This solution was used for old Magento 1 store. It will be updated to new Magento 2 soon. If you are planing still to use Magento 1 store, please use comment from **sv3n**. It is better to create new module for making translation file visible for Magento

Comment: I'd consider it as a bug ... and not fixed in 1.9.4.x